# Discrete Random Variable Transformation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

i have a problem and i can't figure out any solution.

Suppose i have this game:
i throw a die untill i get a 6. 
Every time i throw the dice i pay -1 and when i get the 6 i win 5.
(Nb: when i obtain the first 6 the game end).

I call $X$ a radom variable that is the number of attempts to get a 6. 
$X$ has a geometric distribution with parameter $\theta = \frac{1}{6}$.

Now define a variable that tells me how much i win/loss: $Y = 5 - X$; this is my transformation.

The problem is that i don't know how to compute the Cumulative distribution function for the $Y$.

I tried: $F_Y(y) = P(Y \le y) = P(5 - X \le y) = P(X \ge y - 5) = 1 - P(X < y-5) = 1 - F_X(y -5 -1)$ 
sustituting:
$F_Y(y) = 1 - (1 - (\frac{5}{6})^{y - 6}) = (\frac{5}{6})^{y - 6}$

That is wrong!
Can you help me finding the mistake?

Thank you,
bye.

Comment: The singular of "dice" is "die".

Comment: It seems that it would be easier to find (i) the possible values of $Y$, (ii) the probabilities that $Y$ takes on each of these values, and (iii) adding up $P\{Y = n\}$ for all $n \leq y$ to get $F_Y(y)$. Note that $F_Y(y)$ is defined for all real numbers $y$, not just for integer values of $y$.

Comment: Yes, maybe in this specific case it is easier...but i'm searching for a general procedure to solve this kind of problems..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
 \mathbb{P}(Y \leqslant y) = \mathbb{P}(5-X \leqslant y) \stackrel{\color\red{\text{!!!}}}{=}  \mathbb{P}(X \geqslant 5-y) = 1-\mathbb{P}(X < 5-y) = 1 - F_X(4-y)
$$
Compare this with your answer $1-F_X(y-6)$.

Comment: OkOk Sasha i got it, thank you!
Just a correction..i think it is: $1 - F_X(4 - y)$

Comment: @Aslan986 Thanks, I have corrected the typo